# Not expected "Requests too large" exception in gremlin query [azure-cosmosdb]

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We were experiencing some issues with RequestRateTooLargeException  .
I would like to get some insights.

If I tried to run this I get the Exception:

```
g.V('e078e211-460c-4b18-bf03-e68313dabdcc').as('u').V('0b30599f-ae5b-4cde-9fb3-06c44d54d792').inE('follows').where(outV().as('u'))
```

Should not be this a very simple query?
This particular vertex has a lot of "Follow" edges.
If I try with a different vertex with only a few "Follow" edges the query consumes 11RUs.
The indexes are the default ones.

.NET Framework: net Core 3.1
SDK: Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 2.9.2
Host: Azure Fabric

Thanks in advance
Juan Pablo

Comment: Does your collection have a lot of vertices? Does it have a lot of partitions? A vertex and its outbound edge are stored together, so outbound traversals are relatively inexpensive. Searching the other direction will often require cross-partition searches.

Comment: Thanks David, I changed the command to this => `g.V('0b30599f-ae5b-4cde-9fb3-06c44d54d792').as('u').V('e078e211-460c-4b18-bf03-e68313dabdcc').outE('follows').where(inV().as('u'))` and worked Ok. I Inverted the direction of the query.  It is only one partition but lots of edges from the vertex I was quering.

Comment: hi,Juan. You could summarize your solution as an answer(not in the comment) to en d this case. Thank you for your sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comment from David I changed the gremlin command to

```
g.V('0b30599f-ae5b-4cde-9fb3-06c44d54d792').as('u').V('e078e211-460c-4b18-bf03-e68313dabdcc').outE('follows').where(inV().as('u'))
```

Basically I changed the vertex side used to select the edge I wanted.
As David mentioned, the outbound edges are stored together with the vertex.
This fixed my issue.

I'm not sure if this implementation detail should affect the execution of the command. I should expect that in both cases I receive the same result.